# $E\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ measurable and $0<m(E)=p\leq +\infty$ $\Rightarrow$ $\exists A\subseteq E$ bounded so that $m(A)=q<p$

Tags: measure-theory

Let $E\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ be a measurable set and $$0<m(E)=p\leq +\infty.$$ Prove that there exists a bounded set $A\subseteq E$ so that $m(A)=q<p$, for a previous given $q$.

I have proven that if $E$ is bounded the given problem is true. Now I assumed that $E$ isn't bounded. For that our TA has said that we should use the sequence $(E_n)$ defined as $$E_n=E\cap [-n,n],\; \forall n\in \mathbb{N}$$ I have proven that $(E_n)$ is a monotone growing sequence. But I don't know how to use that information, so if anyone has any tips, I am open for any idea.

Comment: Since the measure $m(A)$ is supposed to be precisely $q$, I think you might want to use sets $E_r = E \cap [-r,r], r \in \mathbb{R^+}$. Then $m(E_r)$ should be an increasing and continuous function of $r$, with $\lim_{r \to \infty} m(E_r) = p$, and then the intermediate value theorem will give you the desired conclusion.

Comment: @Malman Can you explain the part with thee intermediate value theorem. I don't get that part really.

Answer (score 0):

Your $E_n$ is bounded and $m(E_n) \to m(E)$. Hence, there is an $n$, such that $m(E_n) > q$. Now apply the first part of your proof.